# TypeError: force_login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Tags: python, django, docker

Test cases not able to run because of

TypeError: force_login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

test_admin.py

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse


class AdminSiteTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client
        self.admin_user = get_user_model().objects.create_superuser(
            email='tata@nano.com',
            password = 'password1234'
        )
        self.client.force_login(self.admin_user)
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            email='tata@nano.com',
            password='password1234',
            name = 'Ratan jamshed tata'
        )

    def test_users_listed(self):
        """Test user that are listed on user page"""
        url = reverse('admin:core_user_changelist')
        res = self.client.get(url)

        self.assertContains(res, self.user.name)
        self.assertContains(res, self.user.email)
```

Error :

```
>docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py test && flake8"
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E....
======================================================================
ERROR: test_users_listed (core.tests.test_admin.AdminSiteTests)
Test user that are listed on user page
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/core/tests/test_admin.py", line 14, in setUp
    self.client.force_login(self.admin_user)
TypeError: force_login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

I have imported  import authenticate, login in django.contrib.auth but still its not working.

Comment: `self.client = Client()`

Comment: use **`self.client = Client()`** instead of `self.client = Client`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't correctly initialized Client in your code.
Use **self.client = Client()**  to get Client class.
More about Django testing tools can be found in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/